# Cannot access remote table after parallel/insert direct load txn

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

This is the Oracle error message I'm getting ORA - 12840.
We just upgraded from 10i to 12c version and some of the processes aren't working as they did before. I get this error when I execute a `CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT ...` and within the `SELECT` statement there's a call to a function. This function recovers information from another database so I'm guessing this is the root of the problem, but calling the function outside the create table works with no problem at all. I reckon there must be some parameter adjustment that is not set up properly for this kind of operation, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Are you on RAC?

Comment: I found a few workarounds to this problem described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70374031/409172).